# Freestyle Cell Shading flickering problem

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I’ve made freestyle Black/White outline and for an unknown reason, some of the outlines flicker. Often I can freestyle rendering lines even if it’s behind other mesh which seems to work pretty randomly.
Does anyone know any fixes?
I’ve tried searching on google but nothing seemed to work.
I’ve tried Blender discord, nobody seems to know the fix.
I have had this problem since December 2021 and it kinda stopped this project for me after half of the year of work.

Here is a video showing this problem:
https://youtu.be/ouWvcSiaeyg

[image: Here is my freestyle config. It's very basic]